# How to convert the symbol $d$ in Integrate into $\mathrm{d}$?

Tags: latex

I used

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[Integrate[x^2, {x, 1, 2}]]]
```

to convert the integral

$$\int_1^2 x^2 \, dx$$ How to get $$\int_1^2 x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x ?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach using string replacement:

```
dIfy[str_] := CopyToClipboard@OutputForm@
    StringReplace["$" <> ToString[str] <> "$", "dx" -> "\\mathrm{d}x"];

tex = TeXForm[HoldForm[Integrate[x^2, {x, 1, 2}]]];
dIfy[tex]
```

$$\int_1^2 x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Per VF1's suggestion, here is an improved version:

```
dIfy[str_] := CopyToClipboard@OutputForm@
    StringReplace["$" <> ToString[str] <> "$",
     "d" ~~ x_ :> "\\mathrm{d}" <> x];
```

The problem of course is that this matches any `d`, so clearly this string approach isn't going to be the ideal for general usage. At least not without some involved string patterns.

**Edit**. Implementing luyuwuli's suggestion:

```
SetAttributes[dIfy, HoldFirst];
dIfy[int : Integrate[_, varsSpec__]] := Module[{vars, strform},
  vars = ToString[If[ListQ[#], First[#], #]] & /@ {varsSpec};
  strform = ToString[TeXForm[HoldForm[int]]];

  CopyToClipboard@
   OutputForm["$" <> StringReplace[strform,
          ("d" ~~ # -> "\\mathrm{d}" <> # &) /@ vars] <> "$"]]

dIfy[Integrate[z x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, z]]
```

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-1}^1\int \left(z x^2+y^2\right)\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$

For educational purposes, here's the first version I made. It works the same while being less coherent, but it shows a typical use-case for `Fold`:

```
repl1[str_, sym_] := StringReplace[str, "d" <> sym -> "\\mathrm{d}" <> sym];

SetAttributes[dIfy, HoldFirst];
dIfy[int : Integrate[_, varsSpec__]] := Module[{vars, strform},
   vars = ToString[If[ListQ[#], First[#], #]] & /@ {varsSpec};
   strform = ToString[TeXForm[HoldForm[int]]];
   CopyToClipboard@OutputForm["$" <> Fold[repl1, strform, vars] <> "$"]];
```

Comment: Perhaps `"d"~~x_ :> "\\mathrm{d}"<>x` would be a more suitable replacement rule?

Comment: @amr `"\, d"` is only seen in the one-dimensional integral. For the multi-dimensional situation, _Mathematica_ will output something like:\int _1^2\int _1^2x y^2dydx

Comment: @luyuwuli d'oh! fixed

Comment: I don't understand, my computer doesn't run.

Comment: @amr Actually I'm thinking how to deal with even more general situations. i.e. If one variable in the integrand has name with letter **d** like "det", after running your code, "det" will be wrapped by \text{}. In order to deal with the most general situation, I have an idea that before changing the integral to `TexForm`, we have to extract the actual integral parameter first(in this case "x"), then change the expression to string, then replace the "d". But temporarily I don't know how to do that. Wish you can make it:)

Comment: @minthao_2011 the answer will be automatically copied to your clipboard, you only need to paste the answer to your TeX-editor.

Comment: @amr I've posted [a new question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/string-replacement-to-make-the-texform-output-beautiful) related to this topic. Your code will replace all the d to $\mathrm{d}$. Hope you can improve my code:)